# renderDataTable() not taking up the whole page height

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, dt, flexdashboard

I'm using flex_dashboard in R and have the following shiny output using renderDataTable but it's not taking up the whole page

[image]

The page code is as follows in RMarkdown:

````
Column {.sidebar data-width=260}
-----------------------------------

```{r q5_input}
inputPanel( *input panel code *)
```

Column
------------------------------------

```{r q5_output}
renderDataTable({
  *output code*
})
```
````

How can I make the datatable take up the whole page?

Comment: What do you mean by "take up the whole page"?  Your table already takes up the full width of its panel.  To show more rows in the table, you can add `pageLength=<x>` to the datatable call, where `<x>` is an integer.  But you have only 18 rows in your data frame, so even the whole table won't occupy the full height of the panel.  You can see more details [here](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/options.html).

Comment: @Limey `pageLength` won't help. There are 10 entries to be shown, however only 2.5 are visible and a vertical scrollbar appears. I guess this is what OP is referring to.

Comment: @ismirsehregal  Fair point.  Clarity from OP would help!

Comment: @Limey - yep, this is rare here regarding the questions in general... Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to put this CSS chunk at the beginning of your **Rmd** file:

````
```{css}
.datatables.html-widget.html-widget-static-bound { 
  height: auto !important;
  width: 90vw !important;
}
.dataTables_scrollBody {
  height: unset !important;
}
```
````

---

**A fully reproducible example:**

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output:
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
runtime: shiny
---

```{css}
.datatables.html-widget.html-widget-static-bound { 
  height: auto !important;
  width: 90vw !important;
}
.dataTables_scrollBody {
  height: unset !important;
}
```

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(datasets)
library(DT)
```

```{r q5_output}
renderDataTable({
  iris
})
```
````